# animate a widget continuously different size

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

i am trying to create a splash screen that contain animation, of 3 widget.

i notice this:

1. if the 1st widget animate up the 2nd widget will animate down continuously
2. while the 3rd flip from right to lift.

How do i move 2 widget  with little animation. i using stack with positioned widget in the design.

here is the design code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/splash.png",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: -150,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -math.pi / 4.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      width: 300,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 25,
                      width: 400,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 15,
                      width: 210,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 10,
              top: -120,
              child: Center(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Un',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 45.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Animator(
                      tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 6.35),
                      cycles: 1,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 8),
                      builder: (context, anim, child) => Transform.rotate(
                        angle: 0,
                        child: child,
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/white_lgo.svg",
                        width: 50.w,
                        height: 35.h,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'leap',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 45.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: -140,
              bottom: 320,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -math.pi / 4.0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      width: 140,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff103E3F),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 25,
                      width: 70,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff103E3F),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 13,
                      width: 300,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff103E3F),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

the animation i am trying to achieve
[expected](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15otqi2D_kqAsqdwQsaEqgJwBYK5GVSIL/view?usp=sharing)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create an animationController like this:

```
late final AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  vsync: this,
);
```

and then add an animation. This code will generate numbers and you can use these numbers writing _doubleAnimation.value wherever you wanna change. For Example:

```
late final Animation<double> _doubleAnimation = Tween<double>(
     begin: 0.0,
     end: 6.34,
   ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animationController,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
   ));
```

and run this function for infinity animation in initState:

```
animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
```

If you don't wanna reverse animation, you can change reverse to false.

Lastly, do not forget to use TickerProviderStateMixin. Also, you can take some help from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial)